# How to set the user permissions for ios facebook sdk 3.2

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql

I am upgrading facebook SDK 3.0 to 3.2. I have done the facebook login through facebook SDK 3.2 and which is working fine. I would like to execute fql to get the user's album. The below code works for get the facebook photos but not to the albums because of users permissions. I am struck on how to set the "user_photos" permission for facebook sdk 3.2. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *query =
@"SELECT pid, src_small, src_big, src FROM photo WHERE aid IN "
@"SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 50";

NSDictionary *queryParam =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }
                      }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that the above code works for getting the photos, which means that you already have the "user_photos" permission that is required to fetch the user's albums (it's the same permission for both, see [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)).

**If that is really the case**, you can fetch the albums easily with the following query:

```
SELECT aid, name, link, cover_pid 
FROM album 
WHERE owner = me()
```

**Otherwise, if you are really missing the permission** it means you cant get the user's photos either. In that case, you will have to ask the user to reauthorize with the relevant permission. You can just call the regular `FBSession` authorization methods with the new permission, and it will prompt the user for it.

Anyways, I would advise you to use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test your FQL queries, it will help you to easily recognize what is the problem.